# Populating select, based on previous select on jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jsp

I have never been writing code in JS or JQuery, I tried different solutions but none of them worked for me. My problem is the following:

I have a `java` class `Product` which has 3 fields : `id`, `type`, `model`. I pass `ArrayList` of `Product` to a jsp as `${products}`.

in jsp I have two select fields,

1. Asks you to choose type of product
2. Asks you to choose model based on type of product you chose

Here is my most recent code:

```
<br>Choose Type
<select name="productType" form="addRequest" id="productType">
    <option value="EXHAUST">EXHAUST</option>
    <option value="HEATER">HEATER</option>
    <option value="BOILER">BOILER</option>
    <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
</select>

<br>Choose Model
<select name="productModel" form="addRequest" id="productModel">
    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
         <option value="${product.getModel()}">${product.getModel()}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>

<script>
    $("#productType").change(function () {
            var productList = ${products};
            var chosenType = $("#productType").val();
            productList.filter(function (p) {
            return p.getType() == chosenType
                })

            $.populateSelect($('#productModel').get(0), productList)
    })
</script>
```

Comment: It is better idea to filter models by product type in server side. Are you loading models and product types from database?

Comment: @bpu yes, I am loading data from DB. In order to filter it on a server side I would need to make extra http requests and controllers, which I don't want to do knowing that there is jQuery. To be honest, it's not the only page which requires this filtering.

Comment: I suggest to implement new controller which takes product type Id as input and forms Json response. It requires to send extra query to database by adding where clause. Filtered data can be retrieved by jquery get request and then new options applied to select. 
As your current solution, It is kind difficult to parse ArrayList in jsp page. And it is an overload to server and database returning all records (depends on records amount).

Answer (score 0):

Quick sollution:

```
<br>Choose Type
<select name="productType" form="addRequest" id="productType">
    <option value="EXHAUST">EXHAUST</option>
    <option value="HEATER">HEATER</option>
    <option value="BOILER">BOILER</option>
    <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
</select>

<br>Choose Model
<select name="productModel" form="addRequest" id="productModel">
    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
         <option value="${product.getId()}" data-type="${product.getType()}">${product.getModel()}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>

<script>
     $("#productType").on("change", function() {
        var chosenType = $("#productType").val();

        $("#productModel > option").each(function() {
            if($(this).data("type") != chosenType) {
                $(this).css("display","none");
            } else {
                $(this).css("display","block");
            }
        });

        $("#productModel").selectpicker('refresh');
    });
</script>
```

Alternative solution is to send ajax request to server for filtering particular product models only.